# Appending DataFrame to empty DataFrame in {Key: Empty DataFrame (with columns)}

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am struggling to understand this one.

I have a regular df (same columns as the empty df in dict) and an empty df which is a value in a dictionary (the keys in the dict are variable based on certain inputs, so can be just one key/value pair or multiple key/value pairs - think this might be relevant). The dict structure is essentially:

```
{key: [[Empty DataFrame
Columns: [list of columns]
Index: []]]}
```

I am using the following code to try and add the data:

```
dict[key].append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

The error I get is:

```
temp_dict[product_match].append(regular_df, ignore_index=True)
TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments
```

Is this error due to me mis-specifying the value I am attempting to append the df to (like am I trying to append the df to the key instead here) or something else?

Comment: Could you give an example of the input dictionary?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, the inputs are based on the number of files in a directory endpoint, and these become the keys (after some modification of the path). the values are then the empty dfs mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary contains a list of lists at the key, we can see this in the shown output:

```
{key: [[Empty DataFrame Columns: [list of columns] Index: []]]}
#     ^^ list starts                                        ^^ list ends
```

For this reason `dict[key].append` is calling [list.append](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) as mentioned by [@nandoquintana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68792453/15497888).

To append to the DataFrame access the specific element in the list:

```
temp_dict[product_match][0][0].append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

---

**Notice** there is no `inplace` version of `append`. [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) *always* produces a new DataFrame:

Sample Program:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

temp_dict = {
    'key': [[pd.DataFrame()]]
}

product_match = 'key'

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (5, 4)))

temp_dict[product_match][0][0].append(df, ignore_index=True)
print(temp_dict)
```

Output (`temp_dict` was not updated):

```
{'key': [[Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []]]}
```

The new DataFrame will need to be assigned to the correct location.

Either a new variable:

```
some_new_variable = temp_dict[product_match][0][0].append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

`some_new_variable`

```
    0   1   2   3
0  99  78  61  16
1  73   8  62  27
2  30  80   7  76
3  15  53  80  27
4  44  77  75  65
```

Or back to the list:

```
temp_dict[product_match][0][0] = (
    temp_dict[product_match][0][0].append(df, ignore_index=True)
)
```

`temp_dict`

```
{'key': [[    0   1   2   3
0  99  78  61  16
1  73   8  62  27
2  30  80   7  76
3  15  53  80  27
4  44  77  75  65]]}
```

---

Assuming there the DataFrame is actually an empty DataFrame, `append` is unnecessary as simply updating the value at the key to be that DataFrame works:

```
temp_dict[product_match] = df
```

`temp_dict`

```
{'key':     0   1   2   3
0  99  78  61  16
1  73   8  62  27
2  30  80   7  76
3  15  53  80  27
4  44  77  75  65}
```

Or if list of list is needed:

```
temp_dict[product_match] = [[df]]
```

`temp_dict`

```
{'key': [[    0   1   2   3
0  99  78  61  16
1  73   8  62  27
2  30  80   7  76
3  15  53  80  27
4  44  77  75  65]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an empty list at `dict[key]`?

Remember that "append" list method (unlike Pandas dataframe one) only receives one parameter:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html